# KeyWait for multiple keys?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I got this function from here : https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=82&t=126256

It waits for one or multiple keys to be pressed :

```
    Key_Wait_Multi(keys, options := "") {
        ih := InputHook("L1 " options)
        ih.KeyOpt(keys, "E")
        ih.Start()
        ih.Wait()
        return (ih.EndReason = "EndKey")
    }
    if Key_Wait_Multi("a{SC34}{F12}","T2") {
        MsgBox("you pressed on of the listed keys")
    }
```

while waiting, I want when pressing any other key different from the listed keys e.g "c" I want it to be sent (written) from the first press no from the second press.
Because now, while waiting, when I press non-listed key e.g "c" nothing happens from the first press But when I press It again (second press) It send "c".

Any help to do so Please!